# How to add movement of player on board made by pictures used in array of labels

Tags: java, swing

I am doing a project (snake and ladder game)and want to add following functionality.
-Keep track of where each player is on the grid
-Enable the movement of players up ladders and down snakes.

I am making the board having snakes and ladders using array of labels in grid panel. I want to show position of user on the labels. How to do it? Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can consider it as a graph, which would be better represented as adjacency matrix.

Functionality you can add :

1. Moving from current cell (x,y) to other cell say(N) positions away
2. You could keep array of players which would give you information where the players are
3. You can associate the cells in the array with head of snakes and basically keep a map which would tell you where the snake would lead the player to.
4. Similarly you could keep a map of ladders and where they lead you to.

Note : All these maps could take in Point as a key and store Point as a value

Classes you might want to create :

```
Class Point {
int x,y;
// other methods
}

Class Player {
int positionX,PositionY;
// other methods like move(n) .. etc
}
```